# Sending emails by schedule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to send mail on a schedule specified by the admin. Admin can specify two days in which is sending mail. The days which are specified through the admin interface, it days before the termination of activity of the company.

I would use `DelayedJob` for this.

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign

end

class CreateEmails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :emails do |t|
      t.integer :days1
      t.integer :days2

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :emails

  def end_time
    created_at + ends_at.day
  end
end
```

Method `end_time` determines when you are finished with the activity of the company.

`ends_at` this field from the database to fill the admin at creation of the company.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. Are you unsure on how to use `DelayedJob`? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Why do you want to use delayed job? For scheduling?

Comment: @JohnNaegle What other alternatives are there? I prefer DJ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative you can create a rake task to call your method that sends the email, and there is this nifty little gem called [Whenver](https://github.com/javan/whenever), that can be used to set your cron for the automation of the process

Comment: The point is that the administrator sets the time when sending email.

Comment: @user3458697 will the administrator send the time for each company individually?

Comment: for all companies. The administrator may change the time.

Comment: Best practice would be to write a Rake task, as mentioned earlier that checks periodically if any of the companies were required to be emailed since the previous run of the task, Lets say you  schedule your task to run every 15 minutes then you will check if there are any records whose end_time lies in Time.now-15.minute and send them the email.